# Extract date and time using Regex and then covert it to datetime

Tags: pandas, regex, extract

I have a dataframe which has only one column named ImagePath and this is how one input looks like:

```
Images/LINE 58/AGSD/LUC/L58_AFND_K3_2022-10-12_23-53-18_Color_ID_511.jpg
```

This is what I want to extract:

```
2022-10-12_23-53-18
```

This is what I have:

```
dfDate = dfColor['ImagePath'].str.extract(r"^(?:.*?_){3}([^\nColor]+)").to_string()
dfDate = pd.to_datetime(dfDate, format='%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S_')
```

I would not want to create a dependency on that world "Color" as I am doing right now because in the future there might be any other word. I would like to count on the "_" and take everything from the 3rd and 5th underscore.

Comment: Do you need more help with this task? Have you had time to check the solutions below?

Answer (score 2):

Change the regex to

```
^(?:[^_]*_){3}([^_]*_[^_]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FMfde8/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^_]*_){3}` - substring till (and including) the third `_`
- `([^_]*_[^_]*)` - Group 1 (the actual output of `.extract()`): zero or more non-underscore chars, `_` and again zero or more non-underscore chars.

A variation of the solution: you may require the group pattern to match a datetime-like string:

```
^(?:[^_]*_){3}(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2})
```

Or, allowing single digit hours/minutes/seconds/months/days:

```
^(?:[^_]*_){3}(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}_\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FMfde8/2).

Comment: Maybe check the format as well, to make sure it's a date!
`^(?:[^_]*_){3}(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2})([^_]*_[^_]*)`

Comment: @Savageman I added two more variants.

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it

```
# assuming there is a 4 digit following underscore _
# continuing matching until there is underscore and non-digit

_(\d{4}-.*?(?=_\D))


# _ : matches underscore
# (\d{4}- : 4 digits followed by -
# .*? : non-greedy, match all characters
# (?=_\D)) : positive lookahead, an underscore followed by non-digit,
to terminate the match
```

```
df['date']=df['url'].str.extract('_(\d{4}-.*?(?=_\D))')
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'],  format='%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')

df
```

```
    url     date
0   Images/LINE 58/AGSD/LUC/L58_AFND_K3_2022-10-12...   2022-10-12 23:53:18
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, with [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
dfDate = dfColor['ImagePath'].str.split('_').str[3:5].str.join('_')
dfDate = pd.to_datetime(dfDate, format='%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
```

Comment: this works the best with the other code I had. Thank you!